# Как правильно присваивать переменную?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Почему такая конструкция работает:

```
let outputData = document.querySelector('#outputData');
outputData.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';
```

А вот такая уже нет:

```
let outputData = document.querySelector('#outputData').innerHTML;
outputData = 'Введите значение';
```

Складывается впечатление, что методы нельзя добавлять в переменную. Или возможно я не до конца понимаю особенности присваивания переменной.

Кто может объяснить эту ситуацию?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Складывается впечатление, что методы нельзя добавлять в переменную.

Методы можно добавлять в переменную, однако, в данном случае в коде **нет методов**.

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) - это **свойство**, возвращающее строку.

> возможно я не до конца понимаю особенности присваивания переменной.

Особенностей нет: присваивая что-то в переменную, никак не влияет на предыдущее значение переменной.

```
var a = {};
a = 'a';
a = 3;
```

Во всех трех случаях предыдущее значение теряется и никак не меняется.

---

#### Почему работает первый вариант?

В первом варианте: `outputData.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';`

Нет **присваивания переменной**. Есть **изменение значения свойства** объекта.

При этом, `.innerHTML` еще и *особое свойство*, которое разбирает переданную строку и генерирует нужный html, который затем и отображается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, измените *«Есть присваивание свойства объекту»* на *«Есть присваивание свойств**у** объекта»* для однозначности формулировки.

Answer (score 0):

querySelector возвращает ссылку на объект, а innerHTML - строка, базовые типы в js не ссылочные, поэтому когда вы приравниваете строке, то переменная будет типа string, а он базовый и ее изменение не будет менять ее в первоначальном месте. Например:

```js
const simpleType = 'string'
let simpleType2 = simpleType

simpleType2 = 'another string'

// should be false
console.log(simpleType === simpleType2)

const obj = { string: 'string' }
const obj2 = obj

obj2.string = 'another strig'

// should be true
console.log(obj.string === obj2.string)
```

Comment: что-то в объяснении все в кучу смешалось. По нему получается, что если в переменную присвоить объект, а затем присвоить еще что-то, то первый объект должен измениться. Проблема ж не в том, что **присвоили строку**, а в том. что **полностью заменили** значение переменной